# How do I run concurrent scripts when webpack watch fires?

Tags: concurrency, npm, build, webpack, npm-scripts

### Background

I currently have an npm script that looks something like

```json
"dev":"yarn install && concurrently -k \"npm run webpack\" \"cd dist/ && node App.js\" \"npm run test\" \"npm run lint\""
```

Logically this runs webpack, starts the app, lints, and tests in parallel.

npm webpack in that script has --watch set

Note: this is for dev.

### The Problems

- This tries to run the app before it has webpacked
- This won't re-run the app when webpack repacks due to watch

### The Goal

- Run `npm run webpack` once
- When it outputs (meaning the watch fired and finished) run the other three commands
- when something crashes inform me, don't waste time running stuff that won't work, but try again when I fix the file.

### The Real Problem

I don't know what I don't know. I suspect the real answer will be in the webpack config itself potentially, or there's a better tool than concurrently/watch for my use case, or the core idea on how I've designed this is just crazy. Maybe I want to create a devServer.js that uses webpack dev middleware to serve these instead? how would that pull in linting and testing then?

I don't know what a beautiful version of this build would look like.

### What I Really Need

A great tutorial/guide/blog post about how this 'Should' go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do; perhaps there's a better way:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "yarn install && concurrently -k \"npm run webpack\" \"npm run watch\"",
  "watch": "onchange \"dist/**/" -- concurrently -k \"cd dist/ && node App.js\" \"npm run test\" \"npm run lint\""
}
```

This uses [onchange](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onchange). `npm run dev` starts webpack and onchange in parallel. onchange monitors for any file changes in `dist/` and runs your tasks when any files change.

The limitation of this approach is that your tasks will not run until files change in `dist`. You can work around this by deleting `dist/` before running webpack. (Use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) to do this in a cross-platform way.) Example:

```
"dev": "yarn install && rimraf dist && concurrently -k \"npm run webpack\" \"npm run watch\""
```

You can just use `rm -rf dist` if you don't care about Windows support.