# How to run multiple Grunt scripts in the background together?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['browserSync:dev', 'webpack', 'watch']);
```

this is my Grunt-Dev script that I need running while developing. It is run to do three things.

**1) Watch SCSS files for changes then compile them to CSS** (watch + sass)

**2) Start a liveserver with BrowserSync which has reloading built in**

**3) Run a webpack script that watches for changes to js files, and recompiles them into a bundle.js whenever there are changes**

**All of these work, however, I do not want to have three command prompts open every time and have to type out each command. Instead, having them all run with one grunt script is the goal**

its 75% working. I can have SASS/watch + BrowserSync going at the same time with

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['browserSync:dev', 'watch']);
```

This works because BrowserSync has a **watchtask: true** option which means that it will run "in the background". But adding in the third script (webpack) I would need either watch or webpack to have an option like that as well. Because right now, no matter where I place webpack script, either it or the watch scrip will act as a wall for other scripts to run

**here is the full Grunt scripts for reference**

```
 webpack: {
      myconfig: function() {
        return {
          entry: './app/src/js/App.jsx',
          output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src')
          },
          watch: true,
          mode: 'production',
          devtool: "source-map"
        };
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      dev : {
        bsFiles: {
          src : ['app/**/*', '!app/src/js/*.js', '!**/*.scss']
        },
        options: {
          server: {
            baseDir: "./app"
          },
          watchTask: true,
          notify: false
        }
      }
    },

    sass: {
      dist: {
        options:{
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'app/scss',
          src: ['theme.scss'],
          dest: 'app/',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
          spawn: false
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently or https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent?

Comment: yes it just does what my own task does. Once it gets to Webpack or watch then it gets "hung" on that task because it is literally running and wont stop until done. I thought maybe webpack or watch would have an option for "running in background".... Another option is having two watch tasks (one for scss and one for webpack) and doing it manually. but I dont think its possible to have two watch tasks either

Comment: Concurrently should help ... check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212545/how-do-i-run-concurrent-scripts-when-webpack-watch-fires